# Subring of polynomials

Tags: commutative-algebra, polynomials

Let $k$ be a field and $A=k[X^3,X^5] \subseteq k[X]$.

Prove that:

a. $A$ is a Noetherian domain.

b. $A$ is not integrally closed.

c. $dim(A)=?$ (the Krull dimension).

I suppose that the first follows from $A$ being a subring of $k[X]$, but I don't know about the rest.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: For an easy example of a subring of a Noetherian ring which is not Noetherian: Let $D$ be a non-Noetherian domain. $D$ is a subring of its field of fractions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a) Not every subring of a noetherian ring is noetherian (there are plenty of counterexamples), so this doesn't work here. Instead, use Hilbert's Basis Theorem.

b) The element $X^2 = \frac{X^5}{X^3}$ is in $\mathrm{Quot}(A)$. Try to show that it is integral over $A$, but not in $A$.

c) The dimension is the transcendence degree of $\mathrm{Quot}(A)$ over $k$. But this field is easy to compute.

Comment: a) You mean thinking $A=k[X^3,X^5]=(k[X^3])[X^5]$ and use Hilbert two times, once for the () and then for A? c) $X^2 \in Quot(A) \Rightarrow X=X^3/X^2 \in Quot(A) \Rightarrow Quot(A)=k[X]$? As for b), it's clear that $X^2 \notin A$, but for integrality, it's one of my weak spots.

Comment: Well, think about it a while ...

Comment: Certainly I will. But was I right about a) and c) in my comment above? :)

Comment: sorry, I meant: $Quot(A)=k(X)$, of course.

Comment: I think I can conclude that $X^2\in Quot(A)$ is integral over $A$ by saying that $A[X^2]$ is a f.g. $A$-module. The argument may be a bit to intuitive, though.

Comment: Take $f:k\[X_1,X_2\]\rightarrow k\[X^3,X^5\]$ homomorphism of $k$-algebra from $k\[X_1,X_2\]$ onto $k\[X^3,X^5\]$ defined by $f(X_1)=X^3$ and $f(X_2)=X^5$. Then  $k\[X^3,X^5\]$ is quotient ring of an noetherian ring, so noetherian too.

Comment: Thank you. As for integrality of $X^2$ over $A$, I finally found 2 basic examples $p,q \in A[Y], \ p(Y)=Y^3-X^3\cdot X^3$ and $q(Y)=Y^4-X^3\cdot X^5$ for which $p(X^2)=q(X^2)=0$, hence the conclusion. I now call the problem solved. Thanks to all the comentators!